# Custom command completion

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a plugin, where the `b:Sdir` will take the directories with source code. I am trying to achieve autocompletion as:

```
"MakeMake: Generate Makefile.gen
function! MakeMake()
  let b:Rdir = input("Project root folder: ", ".", 'file')
  exe ":lchdir ".b:Rdir

" More than 1 files can be choosed
  let b:Sdir = input("Choose source dir: ", ".", "customlist,CFile")
endfunction

function! CFile(A,L,P)
  return split(globpath(b:Rdir, a:A),"\n")
endfunction
```

But this is not working.
As normal, if I use  "`split(globpath(b:Rdir, "*"),"\n")`" in `CFile`, it will show ALL files in the directory available, but not filter the files.

How can I achieve completion for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need a better glob pattern. Your pattern will only search for exact matches. So add a wildcard and `/` at the end.

```
return split(globpath(b:Rdir, a:A . '*/'), "\n")
```

You probably want to take this a step further and remove the starting directory that `globpath()` gives back via `map()`:

```
return map(split(globpath(b:Rdir, a:A . '*/'),"\n"), 'v:val[strlen(b:Rdir)+1: -1]')
```

Or even better, forget the custom completion all together and just use `dir`. e.g. `input("Choose source dir: ", ".", "dir")`

For more help see:

```
:h globpath()
:h glob()
:h :command-complete
```

Comment: Hi Peter, your glob (and input()'s completion) only eliminates files and searches for directory. I am looking for `foo<tab>` to show files/dirs starting with foo (eg. foobar)

Comment: I would recommend against defaulting to `.` as your glob pattern would translate to something like `../foo*/` for an entry of `./foo`. This is not what you want.